# Lambda join between date range

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I need to join a weekending table to a result on another table.

How can I write this sql query in lambda

```
SELECT * FROM DBS
INNER JOIN WeekEnding WE 
ON DBS.ResultDateTime BETWEEN WE.StartDateTime AND WE.EndDateTime
```

I'm not sure how to join the between start weekending and end weekending selector. this is what i have

```
var newQry = qry.Join(_context.WeekEnding, dbs => dbs.ResultDateTime, we => 
we.StartDateTime && we.EndDateTime, 
(res, we) => new DBS
{
        ....        
});
```

Comment: I will never understand why people use entity framework. Why don't you just use an ORM that supports SQL?

Comment: @Liam Often it's because you start working at a company that already uses EF and they will not even entertain the idea of giving up precious development time to switch ORMs. If you dislike EF but you are forced to use it, you can write your SQL in a stored procedure and just have EF call that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple `from` clauses to achieve a `cross join` and then filter on the conditions:

```
from we in _context.WeekEnding
from dbs in _context.DBS
where dbs.ResultDateTime >= we.ResultDateTime
&& dbs.ResultDateTime <= we.EndDateTime
select new (we, dbs)
```